# efficient way to select many records from oracle database(or in short time)

Tags: database, oracle

I am currently develop a program to retrieve records from database based on numbers of tables.

Here is my sql cmd string.

```
select distinct a.id,
                a.name,
                b.status,
                b.date
from table1 a
left join table2 b
    on a.id = b.id where #$%^$#%@
```

And some of the tables have around 50 millions of records or above. At most of the time, the sockets will not return timeout error because users will input the where clauses for what they want. However, when the program try to retrieve all the records from the database, it will show socket error because it takes too much time to retrieve which is not allowed.

One of my through is that to limit the rows retrieved by using rownum because users might not really want so many datas from the tables. For example, user can input the max number of rows that they want to retrieve 10 thoursands records. And I will return 10000 records back to them. But I fail to retrieve same exact number of records by using rownum < 10000 and I don't know how it can work too....

And so here I am to ask for any suggestions from professional developers here. Please help! Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Keep in mind that limiting or paging does not always work as a shortcut as an operation might need to finish completely. This could be the case for a sort or for certain set operations. Besides that, setting a request limit and a `SELECT * from () WHERE ROWNUM < 1000)` (both together) does allow the expression to shortcut. You can also use `select cound(*)` first. Besides that, it might be an idea to not hard termante the statements but use a low prio consumer group and put runaway sessions into it with the (Oracle) resource manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to make it clear (to yourself) what data you need.

If you need to generate overall statistics, then you need all data. Saving intermediate results may help, but you still have to read everything. In that case set the socket timeout to some 24 hours, just make sure your SELECTs don't block other processes.

But if you are making a client application (displaying some data in an HTML table), then you definitely do not need everything. Design your application so that users apply filters first, then they receive the first result page, then the second... See how Google search or e-shops work - you get an empty homepage first (possibly with some promotion), after that you start filtering.

Secondly, technical ideas:

- Limit was implemented in Oracle 12, so you can use `SELECT * FROM table OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY`. For older versions you have to use the old `WHERE rownum <= 10000`, which does not work well with `ORDER BY`.
- Save intermediate results when using aggregations, etc.
- Minimize the need of JOINs (denormalize).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of using an optimizer hint to tell Oracle that you want the first n rows fast like described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#4942

Answer (score 0):

Other two answers already mention that you can implement paging using `order by` clause and `rownum` like this:

```
select * from (
  SELECT *, rownum rnum FROM (SELECT foo FROM Foo ORDER BY OFR_ID) WHERE rownum <= stopOffset 
) where rnum >=startOffset
```

or by using `OFFSET` in modern Oracle. 
I want to point out additional thing which shows up when you want to retrieve *many* (like hundrend thousands to millions) rows to process them in application - be sure to set large enough *fetch size* (usually in range 1000 < ? < 5000) in your application when you do it. Typically there is a big difference in execution time when you retrieve results with default fetch size comparing to retrieving them with larger fetch size when it's known that there will be lot of rows. For example, in Java you can explicitly set fetchSize on your `Statement` object when crafting a query:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setFetchSize(1000);
```

Comment: bad example, because if you offseting by rownum and order in same subquery - it may return not acttual data. see doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm